# type ExceptionPolicyImpl has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate. Microsoft Error

Tags: c#

I'm new to building and receiving the following error msg when trying to debug my program and not able to find the solution. Please someone help:

Error:

```
Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException: Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type ExceptionPolicyImpl, key &quot;General Exception Policy&quot; ---> Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = &quot;Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.ExceptionHandling.ExceptionPolicyImpl&quot;, name = &quot;General Exception Policy&quot;.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type ExceptionPolicyImpl has multiple constructors of length 2. Unable to disambiguate.
```

Code:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ExceptionPolicy.HandleException(ex, "General Exception Policy")) { throw; }
        }
```

Web Config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <configuration>
      <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions"    type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions,     Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup,     System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler"     type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MDS_HE_CS" value="K31fZXPsRsNicTKZjYZEY5fztMAjJakZCPHR0jg/ktpCbA3eOZCRNPUKzyaall3dEH/9WJxtzA0lqnAF8zZd9g=="/>
    <add key="MDS_HG_CS" value="K31fZXPsRsN6eqRj7RG3iVGFHQJHlaKXZ7Wid8/O8n5n1i0PmLRKA99KkjVlX/si2CmQhRimqOUy2NU2rgeaDg=="/>
    <add key="MDS_SG_CS" value="K31fZXPsRsNsK1mZRedCcsX2NTeAU++y10mRWBHyjeJdhMPf4Li57rQhS5bNE40YyMdyn76xQbRQDASc+Hvnmg=="/>
    <add key="MDS_MG_CS" value="K31fZXPsRsM3r7gLICawWaaUMSj4U2tx0feh+eT/BzLaXFBWqFUEF19zpXG7HKvwZKpvEoNi3gBTjoyK5+zb1Q=="/>
    <add key="MDS_TST_CS_2" value="K31fZXPsRsOprCPavJFNNxdlljNGgQ0MVZ1H7bN9t/QRDacO5cEv0Iu6jzkehAeGHy+VJn2um3hgtf8s0tYL9Q=="/>
    <add key="MDS_TST_CS" value="K31fZXPsRsOE2fkrlag8a9x2CK4E35/9G/IxK0WRidmU9Su4O81qAI8CwXPhFU5W5OBMV4k+K523h4nmSt6VlQ=="/>
    <add key="MDS_KEY" value="80e995ebfb724ffca2f11205cb8ad0eb"/>
  </appSettings>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <!--
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" warningLevel="4" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
        <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
        <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.web.extensions>
    <scripting>
      <webServices>
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the authentication service. Include 
              requireSSL="true" if appropriate.

          <authenticationService enabled="true" requireSSL = "true|false"/>
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment these lines to enable the profile service, and to choose the 
              profile properties that can be retrieved and modified in ASP.NET AJAX 
              applications.

          <profileService enabled="true"
                          readAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2"
                          writeAccessProperties="propertyname1,propertyname2" />
          -->
        <!--
              Uncomment this section to enable the role service.

          <roleService enabled="true"/>
          -->
      </webServices>
      <!--
        <scriptResourceHandler enableCompression="true" enableCaching="true" />
        -->
    </scripting>
  </system.web.extensions>
  <!--
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="CNP.MDS.AMS35.Webservice35.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="CNP.MDS.AMS35.Webservice35.Service1Behavior">
        <!-- Service Endpoints -->
        <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="CNP.MDS.AMS35.Webservice35.IService1">
          <!-- 
              Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
              identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
              automatically.
          -->
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="CNP.MDS.AMS35.Webservice35.Service1Behavior">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to add `<loggingConfiguration>` and `<exceptionHandling>` tag for logging in web.config file as I can not able to find in your web.config file.